# Cross-Compiling from macOS to Raspberry Pi 4 with Clang and CMake

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, clang, cross-compiling, libstdc++

Hoping a CMake/Clang guru can help out here!  I'm trying to setup cross compiling from macOS (13.4.1) to Raspberry Pi 4B running Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit full version.  The overall goal is to use `clang` to avoid building and maintaining a toolchain with the end goal of cross-compiling general C++ applications and Qt applications.  I'm trying to get clang++ and ld-lld with the GLIBC-2.31 (since that is what ships with RPi OS) to make everything easy.  Right now, the problem I'm facing is linking libraries.  This example will show pthreads as an example.

Test Code (test.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

void task(std::string msg)
{
  std::cout << "task says: " << msg << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << "GNU LIBC VERSION: " << gnu_get_libc_version() << std::endl;

  std::thread t0(task, "Hello World!");
  t0.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Raspberry Pi Environment

```
aj@raspberrypi:~ $ clang++-13 --version
Debian clang version 13.0.1-6~deb11u1
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
aj@raspberrypi:~ $ lld-link-13 --version
Debian LLD 13.0.1
aj@raspberrypi:~ $ ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u5) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
aj@raspberrypi:~ $ cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
aj@raspberrypi:~ $ ninja --version
1.10.1
aj@raspberrypi:~ $
```

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++-13)

project(clang-cmake-test LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Threads)

add_executable(clang-cmake-test
    test.cpp
    )

target_compile_options(clang-cmake-test PRIVATE
    -stdlib=libstdc++
    )

target_link_options(clang-cmake-test PRIVATE
    -fuse-ld=lld
    )

target_link_libraries(clang-cmake-test PRIVATE
    Threads::Threads
    )
```

If I build and run this code **on the Pi** all is good.

```
aj@raspberrypi:~/Code/clang-cmake-test $ cmake . -GNinja
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 13.0.1
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++-13 - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done (2.5s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/andyjosephson/Code/clang-cmake-test
aj@raspberrypi:~/Code/clang-cmake-test $ cmake --build .
[2/2] Linking CXX executable clang-cmake-test
andyjosephson@raspberrypi:~/Code/clang-cmake-test $ ./clang-cmake-test 
GNU LIBC VERSION: 2.31
task says: Hello World!
aj@raspberrypi:~/Code/clang-cmake-test $
```

Now if I take the same `test.cpp` to the macOS machine we have trouble.

macOS Environment:

```
aj@andys-mbp ~/Code/cross-clang-rpi4 $ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
aj@andys-mbp ~/Code/cross-clang-rpi4 $ ld --version
Homebrew LLD 14.0.6 (compatible with GNU linkers)
aj@andys-mbp ~/Code/cross-clang-rpi4 $ cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
aj@andys-mbp ~/Code/cross-clang-rpi4 $ ninja --version
1.11.1
aj@andys-mbp ~/Code/cross-clang-rpi4 $
```

Some slight differences in versions, but I wouldn't suspect anything troublesome.  I have a sysroot built from the Pi in `sysroot-RPi`

CMakeLists.txt (on Mac)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE aarch64-linux-gnu.cmake)

project(cross-clang-rpi4 LANGUAGES C CXX)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(clang-cmake-test
    test.cpp
    )

target_link_libraries(clang-cmake-test PRIVATE
    Threads::Threads
    )
```

Toolchain File `aarch64-linux-gnu.cmake`

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(TARGET_SYSROOT /Users/<user>/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${TARGET_SYSROOT})

#set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "")
#set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} ${TARGET_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:${TARGET_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig)
#set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${TARGET_SYSROOT})

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET aarch64-linux-gnu)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET aarch64-linux-gnu)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -pedantic")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath-link=${TARGET_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH ${TARGET_SYSROOT})
```

But we can't find `Threads`!

```
aj@andys-mbp ~/Code/cross-clang-rpi4 $ cmake . -GNinja
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.3
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - no
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:226 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Now here's where things are strange - the libraries all appear to be there.

On the RPi with the successfully running code:

```
aj@raspberrypi:~/Code/clang-cmake-test $ ldd clang-cmake-test 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007f8f05b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007f8efe6000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007f8ee0e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007f8ed63000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007f8ed3f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007f8ebca000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007f8f02b000)
```

These files all exist in the sysroot (back on the Mac now):

```
aj@andys-mbp ~/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi $ file lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=e5a4fbb31ac8f9324067dd30930fee0eb32a490f, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped
aj@andys-mbp ~/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi $ file lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=3ef32ad83b058f02cf374e5f892f0587814e4297, stripped
aj@andys-mbp ~/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi $ file lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=8defd8eb01d73f30848d9656f10df58465ab9a2e, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped
aj@andys-mbp ~/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi $ file lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 
lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=7a631ea0164655f48e53fe1b1e0727312e257b39, stripped
aj@andys-mbp ~/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi $ file lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=bcb0be0a4d5929b9244446b6e495b05fd335a306, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped
```

Relevant check from `CMakeConfigureOutput.yaml` on the RPi successfully finding threads

```
    kind: "try_compile-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CheckLibraryExists.cmake:71 (try_compile)"
      - "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:112 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS)"
      - "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:176 (_threads_check_lib)"
      - "CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)"
    checks:
      - "Looking for pthread_create in pthread"
    directories:
      source: "/home/andyjosephson/Code/clang-cmake-test/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-hhuYVD"
      binary: "/home/andyjosephson/Code/clang-cmake-test/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-hhuYVD"
    cmakeVariables:
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ""
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG: "-g"
      CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS: ""
    buildResult:
      variable: "CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_CREATE"
      cached: true
      stdout: |
        Change Dir: /home/andyjosephson/Code/clang-cmake-test/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-hhuYVD
        
        Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja -v cmTC_1d28a && [1/2] /usr/bin/clang++-13   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d28a.dir/CheckFunctionExists.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d28a.dir/CheckFunctionExists.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d28a.dir/CheckFunctionExists.cxx.o -c /home/andyjosephson/Code/clang-cmake-test/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-hhuYVD/CheckFunctionExists.cxx
        [2/2] : && /usr/bin/clang++-13 -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create  CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d28a.dir/CheckFunctionExists.cxx.o -o cmTC_1d28a  -lpthread && :
        
      exitCode: 0
```

Same check on the Mac with a good sysroot that fails:

```
    kind: "try_compile-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:136 (try_compile)"
      - "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:179 (_threads_check_flag_pthread)"
      - "CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)"
    checks:
      - "Check if compiler accepts -pthread"
    directories:
      source: "/Users/andyjosephson/Code/cross-clang-rpi4/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-SCe8qQ"
      binary: "/Users/andyjosephson/Code/cross-clang-rpi4/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-SCe8qQ"
    cmakeVariables:
      CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET: "aarch64-linux-gnu"
      CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET: "aarch64-linux-gnu"
      CMAKE_C_FLAGS: "-Wall -pedantic"
      CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG: "-g"
      CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS: "-Wl,-rpath-link=/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu"
      CMAKE_SYSROOT: "/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi"
    buildResult:
      variable: "THREADS_HAVE_PTHREAD_ARG"
      cached: true
      stdout: |
        Change Dir: /Users/andyjosephson/Code/cross-clang-rpi4/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-SCe8qQ
        
        Run Build Command(s):/opt/homebrew/bin/ninja -v cmTC_b82fb && [1/2] /usr/bin/clang --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi   -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_b82fb.dir/CheckForPthreads.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_b82fb.dir/CheckForPthreads.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_b82fb.dir/CheckForPthreads.c.o -c /Users/andyjosephson/Code/cross-clang-rpi4/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-SCe8qQ/CheckForPthreads.c
        [2/2] : && /usr/bin/clang --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi -Wall -pedantic -Wl,-rpath-link=/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu CMakeFiles/cmTC_b82fb.dir/CheckForPthreads.c.o -o cmTC_b82fb  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi  -pthread && :
        FAILED: cmTC_b82fb 
        : && /usr/bin/clang --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi -Wall -pedantic -Wl,-rpath-link=/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu CMakeFiles/cmTC_b82fb.dir/CheckForPthreads.c.o -o cmTC_b82fb  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi  -pthread && :
        /Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(pthread_create.o): In function `allocate_stack':
        ./nptl/allocatestack.c:525: undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags'
        ./nptl/allocatestack.c:647: undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags'
        /Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal_internal':
        ./nptl/nptl-init.c:335: undefined reference to `_dl_pagesize'
        ./nptl/nptl-init.c:344: undefined reference to `_dl_pagesize'
        ./nptl/nptl-init.c:360: undefined reference to `_dl_init_static_tls'
        ./nptl/nptl-init.c:362: undefined reference to `_dl_wait_lookup_done'
        /Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function `__pthread_get_minstack':
        ./nptl/nptl-init.c:393: undefined reference to `_dl_pagesize'
        /Users/andyjosephson/Qt-Pi/sysroot-RPi/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(unwind.o): In function `_jmpbuf_sp':
        ./nptl/../sysdeps/aarch64/jmpbuf-offsets.h:52: undefined reference to `__pointer_chk_guard_local'
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
        ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
        
      exitCode: 1
```

If I remove anything `Thread` related, it will compile and run.  I've read that the undefined references to _dl_xxxx are from mixing static and dynamic linking but I can't figure out the magic CMake incantation to get this to compile and link!?!?!?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your CMake config! Check the symlinks in your sysroot. On my system they have not been resolved correctly. Especially for libpthread.so and libdl.so. If the compiler can't find those links he will use the static library :(. You can fix the symlinks to point to the correct file because at least for libothread.so and libdl.so the file to which they are pointing are in the same folder :)

So just remove the existing symlink and create a new one.

Worked for me. I'm now able to cross-compile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).